# what is the difference between using list.copy() in a for loop and in a while loop

Tags: python

**using a while loop**

```
l = [6, 7, 8, 9];

i = 0;
while i < len(l.copy()):
    l.pop();
    i += 1;
print(l);
```

expected *[]* but actual *[6,7]*

**using a for loop**

```
l = [6, 7, 8, 9];

for i in range(len(l.copy())): # or using just l.copy the same result
    l.pop();
print(l);
```

result as expected *[]*

so what is the difference between the two.
why the while loop the l.copy changes but it dose not in the for loop?.

another question i have is when we have something like this:

```
l = [6, 7, 8, 9];

for i in l:
    l.pop();

print (l);
```

we get *[6,7]*
so if i want to have empty list one way of fixing it is using copy like in the example above, but is not very efficient. another way of doing it is by creating a variable that holds the length of the list then use it inside our condition. is there a better way of doing this? , well i am not talking about this particular example,what i want to know is why values inside conditions changes ?, is this happens in all languages or only modern languages like python or js?

Comment: `range(len(l.copy()))` generates a sequence of numbers whose limit is determined before your loop has started. `i < len(l.copy())` is getting the updated length of the list each turn through the loop.

Comment: why does this happens in the for loop and does not happen in the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not in `l.copy()` but in how you use the value:

`while i < len(l.copy()):`

vs

`for i in range(len(l.copy())):`

`range` generates an object that is stored for the whole loop, it uses `l.copy()` only once, during the start of the loop to evaluate the len - it becomes the same as using `range(0, 4)`.

But `while` checks the value each time you it wants to start the loop. By then `l` changes, so `l.copy()` and its length changes.

Another thing to compare is storing the `l.copy()` and then running the while loop:

```
l = [6, 7, 8, 9]

lcopy = l.copy()
i = 0
while i < len(lcopy):
    l.pop()
    i += 1

print(l)
```

In here, out `lcopy` is already a copy, it doesn't change in size during the loop (only `l` changes size and we don't make a new copy each time now!).

> is there a better way of doing this?

Yes. Lists are classes and have methods, you don't have to do things manually most of the time. - `l.clear()`

Comment: even if i didn't use range(len(l.copy)) and used only l.copy it will have the same output.

Comment: Because internally for-looping through a list generates an iterator for it. `for i in my_list` == `for i in iter(my_list)`. And you don't keep that exact copy of the list, so you don't change it. (While `for i in l` would use an iterator of your list that you're changing, hence breaking the iterator.)